# Nsis ToolTips Multiline text

Tags: tooltip, nsis, multiline

How to create multi-line Tool tip in Nsis Installer?
I was tried this code
`ToolTips::Classic $hCtl "some info $\r$\n\ another info"`
but it wasn't worked.

Comment: Try to design your installer without tool tips, they don't work on touch devices.

Comment: It might not support it, I'll take a look at the source this weekend.